# Is it possible with `click` library to limit choices of a command argument, based on the value of a previous argument?

Tags: python, python-click

**The context**

I have a CLI tool named `mytool` written in python 3.9 and using the `click` library for handling CLI commands, arguments and options. Autocompletion is working.

**What I want to achieve**

In a directory `D` I have the following files:

```
name1_version1.zip
name1_version2.zip
name1_version3.zip
name2_version1.zip
name2_version2.zip
name3_version1.zip
```

When running:

```
mytool install <TAB>
```

I want to obtain a list of autocompletion possibilities: `name1 name2 name3`. Then, when choosing `name2` and running:

```
mytool install name2 <TAB>
```

I want to obtain a list of autocompletion possibilities given the `name2` constraint, i.e.: `version1 version2` which correspond to the `name2_version1.zip` and `name2_version2.zip` files.

The content of `D` is changing regularly. New files are added and removed.

Now let's say that new files named `name2_version3.zip` and `name4_version1.zip` are added to the `D` directory. Then, when running:

```
mytool install <TAB>
```

Without having to modify the code of `install` command. I want the completion to providean updated list of autocompletion possibilities, i.e.: `name1 name2 name3 name4`. Then when running:

```
mytool install name2 <TAB>
```

I want the list of autocompletion possibilities to be updated as well i.e.: `version1 version2 version3`.

**How I was thinking to do it**

The `install` `@click.command` will take two `@click.argument` named `name` and `version`.

As existing files in `D` are changing, I want these two `@click.argument`s to be "dynamic choices".

The argument `name` would would have a `type=click.Choice(ToolsFinder.names())` where `ToolsFinder.names()` returns a list of `<name>` part of the files found in `D`. When using autocompletion, possible values for `name` will be extracted dynamically and returned.

When a valid (i.e. existing) `name` is provided, I want to use this value to limit "acceptable" versions to the `<version>` part of the files found in `D` where the files name matches `<name>`.

In other words I would like the argument `version` to have something like `type=click.Choice(ToolsFinder.versions(provided_name_argument_value))`, where `provided_name_argument_value` is the value of the `name` argument.

**The problem**

I don't know how to filter argument values based on previous argument values.

**The question**

Is it possible with `click` library to limit choices of a command argument, based on the value of a previous argument ?

If yes could you please provide a code snippet showing how to declare arguments to be able to do it (or any other kind of example) ?

Comment: did you have a look at [advanced patterns](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/advanced/) for click? it would also be great to see some code of what you tried.

Comment: What advanced pattern were you thinking about ? As far as I know, there is nothing in advanced patterns matching my need, so if I'm missing something, please explain.

Comment: [shell completion](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/shell-completion/#shell-completion)? my bad, it was not listed in advanced patterns.